# optimizing bitwise operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a unsigned integer `N = abcd` where `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` represents bits from `msb` to `lsb`. I want get following numbers

```
x1 = ab0cd
x2 = ab1cd
```

What is the fastest way to do it using bitwise operations in C?

What I'm trying right now is as follows

```
unsigned int blockid1 = N>>offset;
unsigned int key1 = (blockid<<(1+offset))|(((1<<offset)-1)&N);
unsigned int key2 = (key1)|(1<<offset);
```

here offset is the location where I want to insert `0` and `1`.

Comment: I'm guessing that bitwise operations are all constant time operations, so I don't know what would pass up as *fasted* bitwise operations. If what you have works, I don't know that there will be any faster way to do such things.  These operations would map to CPU instructions in most cases anyways/

Comment: is the offset always 2 ?, the position is always at the 3rd bit ??

Comment: No! offset can be anything between 0-30

Answer (score 1):

```
const unsigned int mask = (~0) << offset;  // same as -(2**offset)
unsigned int key1 = N + (N & mask);
unsigned int key2 = key1 - mask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is only 4 bits wide, which means there are a total of only 16 outputs, I would recommend at least testing (i.e. implementing and profiling) a look-up table.

These days, with super-fast ALUs and slow(ish) memories, look-ups are not often faster, but it's always worth testing. A small table means it won't pollute the cache very much, which might make it faster than a sequence of arithmetic instructions.

Since your outputs are pretty small too, the complete table could be represented as:

```
const static uint8_t keys[16][2];
```

32 bytes is very small, and if you do this often (i.e. many times in a row in a tight loop), the table should fit totally in cache.

Comment: 4 bit was just for example. numbers are regular 32 bit wide

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Jasper Neumann's pages about bit permutations. It includes an online code generator. However it may be usefully complex for your specific case (permutation of one bit if we consider the 0 or 1 to be the MSB).

Note: I let you google the adresse since it has no domain name and direct IPs are not allowed by SO.

Comment: My site about bit permutations and other stuff is and was always accessible via http://programming.sirrida.de/ but was redirected to a private server with a semistatic ip address.
Since 2012-10-01 it is hosted on "real" web space. Jasper Neumann